# MAMP Apache2 new vhost 404 error

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp, vhosts, hosts

I'm trying to set up a new vhost like i did several times before.
Im using a mac and mamp and usually configure like this:

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf i enter:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/riggi/PhpstormProjects/LaufschuhSilex/web“
    ServerName laufschuh.local
</VirtualHost>
```

in /etc/hosts i enter:

```
127.0.0.1       laufschuh.local
```

then I restart apache. This usually works and still works for many (>20) other local websites. Only the 2 new sites I'm trying to add wont work and return 404.

Any hints on where to look?

Comment: http status 404 means that the document does not exist, not that the server is not reachable or anything. So most likely your virtual host setup is fine, but the document you request does not exist within that server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a quotation mark formatting issue. Look how the close quote at the end of your DocumentRoot is formatted differently from the opening quote. To make sure the formatting is correct just copy the correct quotation mark (the opening quotation mark) and paste over the closing mark. This is something that can happen when text is copy-pasted from one place to another.

Comment: Absolute life saver!